# TypeScript es6-promise, how do I match Promise constructor

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, es6-promise

Trying this:

```
  init():Promise<mongodb.Db> {
    return new Promise<mongodb.Db>((resolve : (value?: R | Thenable<R>) => void, reject: (error?: any) => void) => {
      this.db = new mongodb.Db("test", new mongodb.Server("localhost", 12017));

      this.db.open((err, db) => {
        if (err) {
          reject(err);
        } else {
          resolve(db);
        }
      });
    });
  }
```

Gives me this:

```
error TS2351: Cannot use 'new' with an expression whose type lacks a call or construct signature.
```

What am I doing wrong? The constructor parameter I copied straight from the class definition of Promise. Tried many, many different ways to do this, none of them worked though. Obviously, hence the question :)

Answer (score 0):

The ES6 promise constructor takes a function that takes the resolve and reject functions as parameters.

A simple example:

```
let executor = (resolve, reject) => {
   if(1>0) {
      resolve("1");
   } else {
      reject("0");
   };

let promise = new Promise<string>(executor);
```

Comment: Sorry, but this doesn't work. For some reason the constructor isn't found. I am targeting module commonjs and es5 since I want this to work in NodeJS.

Comment: that's the ES6 promise, if you are using es5 you most likely are using a thirdparty promise library. They usually follow the same style but there might be diferences. Please share what promise library you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure where you got this definition from.
Is your compiler target set to es6 ?

From `lib.es6.d.ts`

```
/**
 * Creates a new Promise.
 * @param executor A callback used to initialize the promise. This callback is passed two arguments: 
 * a resolve callback used resolve the promise with a value or the result of another promise, 
 * and a reject callback used to reject the promise with a provided reason or error.
 */
new <T>(executor: (resolve: (value?: T | PromiseLike<T>) => void, reject: (reason?: any) => void) => void): Promise<T>;
```

Works fine for me typescript 1.7.5, target es6

This should work for you

```
return new Promise<mongodb.Db>((resolve: (value?: any) => void, reject: (reason?: any) => void) => {
...
 })
```